# Group by returns only the first matching document in mongodb using pymongo, How to retrieve all the matching documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am currently using the first operator. Is there any operator to fetch all the documents?

```
q = col.aggregate([{'$group' : {'_id' : 
 {'DESIGN':"$CURRENT_DESIGNATION","count":{"$sum":1}},
                "NAME":{"$first":"$NAME"},
                "CURRENT_LOCATION":{"$first":"$CURRENT_LOCATION"},
                "CURRENT_DESIGNATION": 
 {"$first":"$CURRENT_DESIGNATION"},
                "PROFILE_URL":{"$first":"$PROFILE_URL"}}}])



for i in q:
    pprint(i)
```

Comment: It looks that there is no need for you to use aggregation at all. Simply fetch all the matching documents with `find`, and then use `count()` on the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$push` aggregation pipeline operator.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/index.html